# why the value of fileCheck is not changing according to bit

Tags: java, variables

I want the value of fileCheck to change when the value of bit is changed

```
class HelloWorld {
    
    static String bit = "1";
    
    static void changeBit(String profile) {
        if(profile.contains("0")) {
            bit = "0";
        }
    }
    
    static String fileCheck = "check"+ bit +"file";
    
    private static void checkFile() {
        System.out.println("val "+fileCheck);
    }
    public static void init(){
        changeBit("file0");
        System.out.println("Value of File from init "+ fileCheck);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloWorld obj = new HelloWorld();
        obj.init();
        obj.checkFile();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Value of File from init check1file
val check1file
```

Comment: `fileCheck` is initialized only once with the value of `bit` at that early time. Use a function instead.

Comment: because `filecheck` is only assigned once when the class is loaded. It doesn't dynamically change its value based on `bit`

Comment: so if I have multiple variables like fileCheck do I have to repeat this same step for all or are there any better way to do this? thanks for the reply

Comment: You do realise there is only one copy of bit for every Hello world class, too, the method of String contains() is being called in a static context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two commentators are right:
Since the value for fileCheck is only calculated once you always see the initial value. You have to update the value whenever the value of `bit` changes. Here is a possible version:

```
static void changeBit(String profile) {
    if(profile.contains("0")) {
        bit = "0";
        fileCheck = "check"+ bit +"file";
    }
}
```

Comment: so if I have multiple variables like fileCheck do I have to repeat this same step for all or are there any better way to do this? thanks for the answer

Comment: The better way depends on what your use case is. I suggester to calculate `fileCheck` whenever there is a change. Others suggested to calculate the value every time you need it (a method `getFileCheck()`). In practice you would put the calcuation where it is less often executed, so it depends if the values change more often than you read them or not.